# Retrieve products based on Discount

Tags: graphql, shopify, graphql-js

I need to retrieve products using discount percentage, but product only contain price. And also tag based filter can be done and now i integrate the filter based on tag and price. But, how can i retrieve product based on tag, percentage and price.

> Is there any way out of stored on array and then display.

Because it was time consuming. Important thing is, i integrate filter based on `storefront graphql access` and pass request to `graphql endpoint` via `ajax request` and `JS`. 
Is there any possible solutions?